# New button does not appear on the list view in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, list-view

I have started using salesforce1 app.I have full access to both Account and Opportunity objects.However,I can see new button on the list view page of Account but not on the Opportunity list view page,please find the below screenshots for the mentioned issue.I tried adding new button on the list view page in salesforce full site,but still this new button is not appearing on the app.

**EDIT**:I have overridden the "New" button of Opportunity object with a Visualforce page, that might be the reason why its not showing up.If thats the case can some one please guide as to how we can shown the "New" button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is 1 important thing you will need to check:

Make sure your visualforce page which overrides the "New" action on the opportunity is marked as "Available for Salesforce mobile apps". To set this, in the setup menu, go to your visualforce page (Develop > Pages), open the visualforce page there and there you will be able to set this checkbox.

Comment: It's great that theGreatDanton awarded a bounty, but can we get feedback from the original poster to see if this is all that was necessary?

Comment: @DavidSchach Apologies for delay in my reply,the above answer came in handy.I had a VF page overridden on click of new button, which in turn redirected to another VF page. I had checked the "Available for Salesforce Mobile Apps" in the main VF page and not the redirected VF page,Once I enabled this option,"New" button appeared on the list View page.Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Was *enjoying* this issue myself... cheers KoenVM!

Answer (score 3):

You may have a conundrum. If you overrode the "New" button with a page that uses apex:pageblock tags, then your page won't be visible on mobile. You'll need to make a "splash" page to sit between the New button and the desktop override page, and it will need to see what kind of device is displaying it, and then redirect accordingly.

If it helps, I feel your pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can create them via Chatter Publisher Actions. See the following post for more detailed information http://www.cloudjedi.com/blog/salesforce/minimize-clicks-publisher-actions-salesforce-1/

Comment: I don't want it as a publisher action, rather as a new button on the list view page of Opportunity,similar to the "New" button on Account list view page in the attached screenshot.

Comment: does the user have the permission for creating new contacts.